Can a vector tangent to a spacelike surface be null?
I'm studying the peeling-off behaviour of zero rest-mass fields, as described in Penrose's paper. In it, he talks about the boundary $\mathscr{I}$ of the conformal completion of an asymptotically simple space-time. This boundary turns out to have the topology of $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{S}^2$. My trouble comes with understanding his lemma I (page 193). I have a different question about the proof of this lemma here. If we assume that the boundary is a null hypersurface (meaning that the pullback of the metric onto the tangent space at every point of the hypersurface is degenerate), we can take a spacelike cross-section $X$ (meaning that the pullback of the metric onto the tangent space of every point of the cross-section $X$ is Riemannian, so has signature (+, +)) of this hypersurface $\mathscr{I}$. This spherical cross-section gets conformally decompactified into the complex plane $X^*$ with complex parameter $\sqrt{2}z$. He defines the vector $m^{*\mu}$ to be the gradient of $-z$ (I don't really understand why this minus is there) in the plane $X^*$, so that if $a$ is a quantity defined on $X^*$, we have $\frac{\partial a}{\partial z} = m^{*\mu} \nabla_\mu^* a$. This then means that $m^{*\mu}$ is tangent to $X^*$, which then to my understanding means that it is a spacelike vector. However, Penrose states that $m_\mu^* m^{*\mu} = 0$, which means that it is actually not a spacelike vector, but a null vector. How can this be the case?

Do you have a link to Penrose's paper that's not behind a paywall?

https://sci-hub.se/10.1098/rspa.1965.0058 seems to work for me

Penrose is using a metric of signature (+, -, -, -), rather than (-, +, +, +). This then means that the pullback of the metric onto the tangent space $X$ is of signature (-, -) rather than (+, +). The vector being tangent to a spacelike hypersurface does not actually mean that every tangent vector has to be spacelike. A surface being spacelike means that the pullback of the metric onto it is spacelike which in this case means that it has signature (-, -). And the pullback indeed has this signature. Because we are also working with complex numbers (since $X^*$ is the complex plane), this then results in this weirdness that nonzero vectors can still have a zero inner product when not being zero and the metric normally being non-degenerate.
